# Remove files from a folder not used in Premiere Pro

Tags: video, premiere, file-formats

I have a folder in which I save all my video recordings, I used some video files in Premiere Pro but I would like to delete those that I haven't used.

The problem is that I have over 3100 files which weight over 1.5 TB and many Premiere Pro projects, it would take me a very long time to open each project and see which files I've used. When I used Vegas Pro I remember that each video I opened, the program made a `.bak` file with the same name, so I knew that I was using that file, but not Premiere.

I hope I've been clear enough, if you know a way to delete the footage that I've never used in any Premiere project, please help me. :D

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Do you want to delete footages, which you didn't use in Premiere or you even didn't import them in Premiere?

In first case I don't know how to delete them.

In second case I think that you can look at the names of cache files, which premiere have created, then open program like “Beyond Compare”, compare “video folder” with “cache folder” by names. And then you should get, which names don't have in cache folder.

This names will be not used. If your cache are full, you will have full list.

Maybe this idea will be useful for you, but I am not sure.